# How do I GRANT ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER to a role?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Our database has a named database role. Our service account is a member of this role. This makes our database creation scripts simpler.

However, I'd like this role to be able to create linked servers.

If I try the following:

```
USE OurDatabase
GO

GRANT ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER TO OurRole
GO
```

...it fails with `Permissions at the server scope can only be granted when the current database is master`.

If I try the opposite:

```
USE [master]
GO

GRANT ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER TO OurRole
GO
```

...then it fails with `Cannot find the login 'OurRole', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

How do I grant linked server permissions to a database role in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx) would suggest that granting a server permission to a database role is not possible (compare to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx) for granting a database permission).

Comment: Fair enough, I'll just update our scripts to use a specific username for these specific permissions.